# why sorting du -h not working as expected?

Tags: disk-usage, sort

I'm trying to sort the output of du command with human-readable flag and I'm getting the results sort only by the numeric value ignoring the extension(i.e G, M, K ...), while when removing the -h flag the results are as expected.

```
:~/du_exmp$ du -h ./* | sort -n
1.0M    ./file2.txt
2.0G    ./file3.txt
 52K    ./file1.txt
:~/du_exmp$ du  ./* | sort -n
104 ./file1.txt
2048    ./file2.txt
4204192 ./file3.txt
```

what is the source of the issue, and how to solve it?

Comment: Similar: [Generic tool to order by size in linux, understanding common unit suffixes](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/458564)

Comment: Post text as text, this image is not accessible. e.g. it is not readable by blind people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sort -h`. From manual `-h, --human-numeric-sort    compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)`

Use `sort --help` to know the command options better.

Comment: thanks! "du -h ./* | sort -h" works.

Comment: Note that both `-h` and `--help` are non-standard extensions of the GNU implementation of `sort`. GNU `sort` is found on GNU systems and on some BSDs (some BSDs have rewritten their own `sort` using the same API at the time of the rewrite though, so would be supporting those options as well).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that what you're seeing is how `sort -n` works. It looks only at the initial leading numeric value of a line (or more generally, if you use `-k`, a field) and sorts on that. It does not understand the `KMG` suffixes at all so it just stops looking for a number when it runs into them.

The easiest thing to do is what you did in your second example: just use `du` without the `-h` flag and `sort` works entirely naturally.

If you really want to keep the more human readable `du -h` output, you'll have to use another intermediate pipeline stage to add the decoded number to the output of `du`, then sort on that, and then optionally strip out the sort key so the output looks just like that from `du`.

Another option would be to use plain `du`, sort the output as you do in the second example, and pipe that output to another stage to encode the plain integers as `du -h` does.

Traditionally, you'd use `awk` for these last two ideas, but `perl` or `python` would work as well.

Comment: Re @tinker's answer: Sorry, I was unaware of sort -h. I'd delete this answer, but I don't seem to have the ability too so do.

Comment: `sort -h` is a GNU extension. Most other `sort` implementations don't support it (`du -h` is also a GNU extension but more widely supported these days). Also doing the sorting *after* adding the KMGTPE suffixes means it could give the wrong order as a lot of precision is lost. So that answer is still useful for people not on GNU systems.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I guessed it was a gnu extension. I've used sort for a very long time, so my reflexes were formed before the gnu stuff was so ubiquitous.